# Change aesthetic things in an app package

Tags: appexchange, fields, app, security-review, label

Suppose I have an app ready to deploy to the AppExchange. It just passed the Security Review, but I see that there are minor changes like a field's, object's or tab's label/name. Such change could be easily done in the interface, and since the application is very simple, it won't require changes in the code.

Is it possible to make the changes, and "avoid" the Security Review before publishing to the AE? Or it is necessary to go through the whole process again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Salesforce does the periodic security reviews (usually between 6 months and 2 years depending on the risk of the app) for all applications after it pass first time. After passing, you can submit any newer version of this application/package through the publishing console by clicking “Start Review” and receive a "passed" result through their semi-automated system.

For a note:

> Salesforce reserves the right to conduct periodic reviews of all
>   offerings. If we find that the app or component doesn’t meet our
>   security requirements, we notify you and provide time to remedy the
>   issue. In extreme cases, we pull the AppExchange listing from public
>   viewing. In this case, you must cease distribution of your offering.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. If I have the app, but it is not published, and it passes the SR, but I want to change some labels, can I do it without re-submitting it to SR or not?

Comment: yes you can do that easily.